# Are logs drom dart:developer are visible in release mode of flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, logging, flutter-release

In release mode of flutter app, are console logs printed out with `log` method from `dart:developer` are visible? From [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/build-modes#release) of release mode we can read that

> Debugging information is stripped out.
> Debugging is disabled.

and I assume it strip out everything printed with `debugPrint` method, but I couldn't found anything about [`log` method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.0/dart-developer/log.html).

Same goes for output with `print` method? Are those prints will be visible for user who will be reading device log output or not? [Dart linter](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/avoid_print.html) only says that print should be avoided in production code, I assume because of print output visibility.

[Chapter in flutter docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/code-debugging#logging) about logging says how to use them but not really answer questions above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, `developer.log` does not display information on the terminal when in release mode.

But `print()` will surely print all in any mode.

You can check that on android devices connected in USB, using `adb logcat` or `adb logcat | grep flutter`

Just be careful not to print large amounts of information with `developers.log`, as it won't truncate the string, as print actually does.

package: https://pub.dev/packages/dart_log

I actually created a package to handle logs(mentioned above), which allows you to define whether or not to print logs in release mode, and define the amount of characters that can be printed.
all logs are linked to the file in exact line that logger was called, so you can click on it, and easily open the file that dispatched the log :)

Answer (score -2):

Think of it this way. Use a logging library that sets up log trees. In the main function block of your app detect Release mode and have that log library remove the log tree which then makes sure no logs under release mode.

Fimber has such a log tree.